# Unable to request the status code of localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using python and flask to create a web API. However I am getting trouble in requesting the HTTP status code of my localhost.

My code:

```
import requests
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    r = requests.get(url="http://localhost:5000/home")
    print(r.status_code)

    return "Welcome!"

app.run()
```

Before adding the line for requesting status code, it works fine in my browser (Chrome) and the command prompt show something like this:

`127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2019 01:03:54] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

After adding the line for requesting, it keeps loading (forever) in my browser and no response in the command prompt.

I have no idea about this problem because it did not show any error and I have read some of the solutions mentioned in other similar problems (like disabling proxy) but it seems not working for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You define a /home endpoint and then you make it request itself as part of request processing. You get an endless recursion. What did you expect to happen? :)

Comment: The reason you only get endless recursion when you check the status code is because requests library does lazy evaluation, it will not make the request until it has to.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from the point of view of the app. It gets a request for `/home` and routes it to `home()`. While servicing that request, the app makes a request for `/home`, which routes to `home()`. During the servicing of that request... and so on until some resource is exhausted.

If you intent is to prove that you can make a request to the app from within the app, target a different endpoint.